# Huge amount of objects in GC finalizer queue

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, server

I am investigating a slow and steady increase in memory footprint of our server .NET application. To facilitate investigation I run a stress test with 6 clients mimicking real load that repeat the same usage pattern over and over.
As I run over overnight I can see the memory footprint goes up for about few hundred MB. Upon analyzing and comparing the server memory snapshots that are 12 hours apart it turns out that most of the difference is due to `ReaderWriterLock` instances waiting in a finalizer queue. There are over 6,000,000 of them!?!

Analyzing my code and looking at the GC roots reveals that all the `ReaderWriterLock` live instances come from `DataSet` instances in our software. So, I went after `DataSet` instance creations to try to eliminate it as much as possible. After cleaning up some code and caching some `DataSet` instances to avoid unnecessary allocations the difference went down by about 25%, but looks like there are more of them.

My questions are:

1. Why there are so many instances in the finalizer queue - not sure what is causing this?
2. I would assume size of finalizer queue can have negative impact on GC and overall application performance (it looks slow to me after a while)?
3. What should I do to reduce the size of finalizer queue? Call dispose on every `DataSet` instance that I do not need anymore?

Note that I am using 'Server' mode GC as our server does process requests in parallel on different threads.

Comment: The GC won't collect unless there is memory pressure, are you saying that this is a memory leak, or there are just a lot of objects pending finalization and no memory pressure to release them?

Comment: @RonBeyer Looking at a '% of time in GC' counter it looks like GC collects a lot, basically the server spends almost half of time doing GC (the value is keep hovering 0-50-100). Perhaps I have too many allocations and GC has problems keeping up?

Answer (score 0):

While I have not managed to figure out why there were so many `ReaderWriterLock` instances in the finalizer queue, I did find a solution to my problem and got rid of them.

Calling `DataSet.Dispose` did not help. Therefore I have started reusing existing `DataSet` instances instead of keep creating new ones because 'someone said that `DataSet.Clear` is slow' - it is not (if at all) in a long run.
This approach completely removed the issue with the finalizer queue instances.

Comment: If you are not using a derived class the only thing calling `Dispose()` on a `DataSet` does is remove it self from `Site.Container` if it has a site and raise the `Disposed` event. It does not even call `Dispose()` on the datatables it owns (which btw all `DataTable` does is just remove from the site container and raise their `Disposed` event too)